# Strip unused runtime functions which bloat executable (GCC)

Tags: c++, gcc, embedded, cross-compiling

I have build the GCC4.7.1 cross-toolchain for ARM (cortex-m3). Now I'm linking an executable from C/C++ code that surely doesn't use some certain STL classes (e.g. `std::string`). Furthermore exceptions and RTTI are turned off.

Though when I'm looking to the target ELF (e.g. using nm), there's a lot of symbols (apparantly from the libstdc++) linked in I wouldn't expect to find there (e.g. `std::exception`, `std::ios_base`, etc.).

**Why is this there, and how can I get rid of this stuff to reduce the `.text` section size of my target?**

A coworker gave me a tip to override some GCC specific stub function:

```
namespace __gnu_cxx
{
    void __verbose_terminate_handler()
    {
        for (;;)
            ;
    }
}
```

This alone reduced the code size about 20KB.
**Are there more such stubs I can override?**

---

**UPDATE:**
OK, I found one really stupid error that removed most of the stuff I was wondering about, when fixing it:
There was an `#include <iostream>` statement left (though nothing called from there) in one of the source files. This will of course link in the static `std::cin`, `std::cout` and `std::cerr` instances and all the stuff that comes along with these.
Removing the `#include <iostream>` statement reduced the `.text` segment about another > 100KB portion.

---

**Nevertheless:**
There's still the `std::exception` and `std::basic_string` stuff I'm wondering about:

```
Namespace summaries:
==============================================================================
Type         Size Namespace 
T             774 'std'
W             184 'std::string::_Rep'
W             268 'std'
W             472 'std::string'
Class summaries:
==============================================================================
Type         Size Class 
T              50 'std::error_category'
T              52 'std::type_info'
T              54 'std::bad_exception'
T              54 'std::exception'
T              68 'std::bad_alloc'
T              98 'std::length_error'
T             214 'std::logic_error'
W             268 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
```

There isn't really much code size used, just about several 100 bytes, so I could live with neglecting it, but would appreciate, if I can get rid of this also.

Since I'm explicitly using no exceptions I wonder why these are still instantiated when linking. Usage of exceptions or not can't be really determined at runtime?!?
The only remaining thing from the `__gnu_cxx` namespace I have left now is

```
Type         Size Class 
T              58 '__gnu_cxx::recursive_init_error'
```

It's another exception class.

---

**FINALLY:**
I used some additional flags to configure the GCC4.7 cross build:

```
--enable-gold=yes 
--enable-lto 
--enable-cxx-flags='-fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fno-omit-frame-pointer'
```

The latter flags are used to compile the libstdc++ and are essentially the same as used for building the target code (which is a reasonable action anyway). Exception references where gone afterwards (including the `__gnu_cxx::recursive_init_error`).

Last thing was, I found an unexpected use of `std::string` in our codebase. After fixing that, the reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >` also disappeared.

So I'm happy with the result now, no more unnecessary, unexpected overhead from libstdc++, no reason not to use C++ in preference over C.

Comment: @CarlNorum For this project I'm using even C++11 ;-) ...

Comment: Seriously... if your compiler adds 20k(!) sections of pure crap to your program, I would strongly recommend changing compiler or switch programming language to C. There is no feature in the C++ language which can justify so much useless overhead.

Comment: @Lundin I think it's just a matter of tweaking the stubs correctly.

Comment: If you can upgrade to GCC 4.8 then building GCC with `--disable-libstdcxx-verbose` disables the verbose terminate handler, so you don't need to stub it out. Building libstdc++ itself with `-fno-rtti` (via the `--enable-cxx-flags` option) will reduce the library size.

Comment: Compiling with `-fno-threadsafe-statics` will get rid of the `__recursive_init_error` dependency, but don't expect things to work correctly if you're using multiple threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Why is this there, and how can I get rid of this stuff to reduce the `.text` section size of my target?**

There might be (static) references for stuff linked in from the `libstdc++`, that will be instantiated no matter if they are called or referenced in the actually executed codepathes.
Carefully search for usage of `#include` statements that contain such reference declarations (e.g. `#include <iostream>`).

When `libstdc++` is build during installation of GCC with different C++ compile flags as used for the finally intended target, there might be unwanted stuff linked in or being instantiated (e.g. the `__gnu_cxx::recursive_init_error` exception class despite usage of the `-fno-exceptions` flag). Use the `--enable-cxx-flags` configuration option to synchronize with the intended target compile flags when building the toolchain.

Also look carefully for unwanted/unexpected usage of certain STL classes in your codebase (e.g. `std::string`), they might compile and being linked without errors or warnings, despite certain features (e.g. `new()`) aren't really supported on your bare metal platform.

> **Are there more such stubs I can override?**

Depending on how 'newlib' was build for the toolchain (see `--en/disable-newlib-supplied-syscalls` configuration option), it might be necessary to override certain or all stubs provided there.

Comment: Interested readers might also want to look here: [Building GCC 4.7.1 ARM cross toolchain on Suse 12.2](http://dev-jungle.blogspot.de/2013/09/building-gcc-471-arm-cross-toolchain-on.html)

Comment: You did not mention in the question that you had no dynamic memory, what do you get from C++ over C?  type safety?

Comment: @nhed I try to avoid it yes, but that's a minor point (if it turns out I need it, I'll implement it). Type safety is an aspect of course, but the main reason to use C++ over C here is usage of templates and template meta programming. If there are things that can be calculated at compile time I prefer this way, instead of doing it at runtime or using obscure macros.

Answer (score 2):

You can never know what using *one* of library functions will pull in. Well, actually you probably can by creating call graph with one of the tools. So what part of c++ std library are you using?

Other than that, I have had success in removing unneeded function from executable by using two methods (none of this on ARM, but methods are not ARM specific):

1. Compile with -ffunction-sections switch, then link with -gc-sections. This puts each function into it's own section and then tells linker to remove unused sections.
2. Use link time optimization (-flto, see gcc manual for details). This lets compiler see "whole" program as if it was single source and will probably let it remove unused functions.

You are already using -Os, right?

Comment: The options from 1. are already used. Using `flto` and `Os` didn't change anything.

Comment: _'So what part of c++ std library are you using?'_ so far I'm using only `std::array` and `std::tuple`.

Comment: If you are using array, then I guess it's no surprise exception is also in there (as out_of_range can get thrown). BTW: also take a look at this (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0474c/Bhcgeaid.html) if you did not already.

Comment: Your link doesn't relate to my toolchain (GCC), but I'll have a look if it supports some similar option.

Comment: Please have a look at my updates. For now your answer doesn't really answer my question(s).

Comment: `-flto` needs to be enabled on GCC configuration (see my updates)

Answer (score 2):

#### Some CFLAGS:

If you don't use `dynamic_cast` or `type_id` in your code, try adding `-fno-rtti`. This will remove some amount of code relating to class hierarchies, and may remove several dozen bytes for each class in your code.

If you use `throw()` frequently in your function specifications, try adding `-fnothrow-opt`. This will encourage GCC to treat `throw()` as the more strict `noexcept` specification (from C++11), which will substantially reduce code size in many areas, since it will not have to construct exception frames.

As a companion to `-fnothrow-opt`, add `-Wnoexcept`. This will warn you when it finds a place to add `throw()` or `noexcept`, and further reduce the number of places exception frames must be constructed.

Also as a companion to above, replace all instances of `new` in your codebase (if any) with `new (nothrow)` and add `-fcheck-new` to your CFLAGS if necessary.

If you're not using threads, you might find a small benefit from `-fno-threadsafe-statics`, which removes code that performs thread-safe initialization of statics.

#### Linker

The new (well, for the last few years) binutils linker has a plugin called `gold`, which performs a number of link-time optimizations, including dead code removal. I don't know off-hand whether `gold` is supported on ARM yet, but this would be useful in substantially reducing the footprint of the standard library you import.

Comment: Thanks, that reads sound! I've already the `-fno-rtti` option set. Will try your other proposals asap! (BTW: No `throw()`specs used in my own code, no `new()` either).

Comment: I've tried the `-fnothrow-opt` and didn't see any change in codesize, but we're not using `throw()` specs in our own code anyway.

Comment: I've been enabling `gold` with the GCC configuration options, and it built fine (see my updates) ...

Answer (score 1):

**Quick fixes**

First, depending on limitations of your target - you may want to consider @Carl's recommendation above.  We made the decision not to use C++ in our cortex m3 platform.

Second, Embedded development tip for reduction in size for C or C++ - kill floating point libs, in many many applications you can just use fixed point math, but some pull these in for the negotiable reasons (like desire to use "%f" in `printf`).

The hint your co-worker gave is probably very specific to your platform, probably it has a hardware watchdog?   So it will be difficult for others who are not familiar with your 
hardware, code, or app to make such quick-fix recommendations.

**Digging deeper**

Did you actually add up the symbols of these libs and that is where you consume most of your .txt section?

The question may not be necessarily what you are not using from that library, but what you are.  It is quite possible that the libraries you "demand" have their own dependencies.

It is a painful process (and maybe there are better ways) but if I were you I would try to remove the libraries you link and see what you really pull in (the STL headers may demand several of these symbols).  If there are no surprises there, and your app only pulls in expected libraries you would need to dig in deeper:

Method 1:
 - Analyze the libstdc++ code  (probably too long to jump into right away)

Methods 2:
 - I have never done this with C++, just with C libs, but the theory should hold - while removing linkage of libstdc++ - add in one object at a time from libstdc++, you can either build from code and use the object files explicitly or you can try and use tools such as `ar` (`ar -t` to list objects and `ar -xv` to extract).  Note that I am not recommending that you cobble up your link command, just if you want to divide and conquer to see why these modules are demanded by the modules you actually use - at the end of the day you may be able to rebuild the library with a set of "without" flags.  Reading the man pages or `ar`, `nm`, `objdump` would probably help in maybe automating some of this if it is taking too long, I have done stuff like that years ago so I don't have my cheat sheets handy.

Comment: Please have a look at my updates. For now your answer doesn't really answer my question(s).

Comment: This answer doesn't really fit the original questions I had, but is the closest description of the process to find where the unused/unwanted code comes from.

Comment: @g-makulik I understand, I answered based on the original question and am not sure what the point in saving few hundred bytes, but if you do you need to see who pulls it in  ... at the very least use `nm -uC` on each of your object files and see which one demands it and then you can dig deeper ...

Comment: I've been using `nm` + my own tool [nmalyzr](https://github.com/makulik/nmalyzr) to accumulate the size of the symbols in various ways.

Comment: Sorry to redraw the accept, but I've tried to give a more canonical answer for the problem. Left the bounty points to you, if that comforts ...

Comment: I appreciate that...  while you have listed the things that worked for your case, the other answers (not mine alone) provided readers with the steps to find THEIR problems which will vary form yours (teach a man to fish and all that :-)  )